# Create VPC endpoint for S3 bucket lambda access using AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cdk

I am building a system using Python flavored `AWS CDK`.

I have a lambda function with an attached `EFS`. To use `EFS`, I am required to put the lambda function inside a VPC. The problem is, I also want this lambda function to retrieve files from a particular `S3` bucket (in the same region). I am getting Timeout errors when doing the retrieval, and upon some research it seems that I need either a `NAT Gateway` (too expensive) or a VPC endpoint to allow access.

How can I build a `VPC endpoint` in CDK to allow my lambda function to talk to my `S3` bucket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: The comment below from @gshpychka is correct - only the `gateway_endpoint` in the vpc definition is required.

Here is what I came up with that seems to work after following the ideas in [this guide.](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/managing-amazon-s3-access-with-vpc-endpoints-and-s3-access-points/)

You need to create both an `S3 access point` as well as a `VPC Endpoint`.

You make the `VPC Endpoint` when creating the VPC. This allows S3 buckets to be accessible from the VPC. You can later add a policy to restrict this access.

```py
self.vpc = ec2.Vpc(
    scope=self,
    id="VPC",
    vpc_name="my_VPC",
    gateway_endpoints={
        "s3": ec2.GatewayVpcEndpointOptions(
            service=ec2.GatewayVpcEndpointAwsService.S3
        )
    },
    nat_gateways=0,
)
```

You later create an `S3 access point` after creating the S3 bucket. This allows access to the bucket.

```py
self.bucket_access = s3.CfnAccessPoint(
    scope=self,
    id="s3_access",
    bucket=self.my_bucket.bucket_name,
    name="bucket-access-point",
    vpc_configuration=s3.CfnAccessPoint.VpcConfigurationProperty(
        vpc_id=self.vpc.vpc_id
    ),
)
```

Comment: You really don't need the access point, a gateway will be enough.

Answer (score 2):

```
export class YourStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const vpc = ec2.Vpc.fromLookup(this, 'vpc', { isDefault: true });

    const s3BucketAcessPoint = vpc.addGatewayEndpoint('s3Endpoint', {
      service: ec2.GatewayVpcEndpointAwsService.S3,
    });

    s3BucketAcessPoint.addToPolicy(
      new iam.PolicyStatement({
        principals: [new iam.AnyPrincipal()],
        actions: ['s3:*'],
        resources: ['*'],
      }),
    );
}
}
```